# The Gettier counter-example: How to formalize its crucial entailment?

Tags: logic, gettier

The Gettier counter-example to the definition of knowledge employs the claim that d) entails e):

> (d) Jones is the man who will get the job, and Jones has ten coins in his
>   pocket.
>
> (e) The man who will get the job has ten coins in his pocket.

See *Gettier, Edmund*: Is Justified True Belief Knowledge? Analysis, 23 (1966).

How does d) entail e) in a formalized language - probably using predicate calculus?

Comment: Using = rules. If $/phi$ can be deducible and c is a constant in Phi, and c=b, then $\phi$' is also deducible where it is obtained from phi by replacing one or more c by b

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a formalization in quantifier calculus with identity:

Premise: GetJob(Jones) ∧ ∀x(GetJob(x) → x = Jones) ∧ HasCoins(Jones)

Conclusion: ∀x(GetJob(x) → HasCoins(x))

By [universal instantiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_instantiation) assume GetJob(a), by the second conjunct in the premise a=Jones, by the last conjunct and substitutivity of identity HasCoins(a). Since a was arbitrary the conclusion follows by [universal generalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_generalization).

Answer (score 0):

This follows directly using the rule of existential generalization. If we assume our universe of discourse is men (this will save a little bit of space) then we could write the sentences as

```
WGJ(j) ∧ (∀y)(WGJ(y) → j=y) ∧ HTC(j)

(∃x)[ WGJ(x) ∧ (∀y)(WGJ(y) → x=y) ∧ HTC(x) ]
```

All one has to do is replace all instances of the name j with an existentially quantified variable x that does not already appear in the sentence.